# Comparision test for this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How do I check divergence of this series?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{6}{4n-1} - \frac{6}{4n+3}$$

Wolframalpha said it used the comparision test but I don't see what possible smaller sum to use?

It's also a telescoping series but I don't know how that is useful in this case?!

Comment: Definitively, $$0\le\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac1{4n+3}=\frac{4}{16n^2+8n-3}\le \frac{\alpha}{n^2}$$ So the series is convergent.

Comment: Why do you think it's divergent? It's sum is $-6$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli but for $n=0$ , first term is $-6$, did I missed something?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan Sorry, I just realised.

Comment: OK, I mistyped my question on wolframalpha... Anyway, so could I just use the fact that it is telescoping and note that only the first term $\frac{6}{-1}$ does not get canceled out?

Comment: Ya that's true but you can also use comparison test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{6}{4n-1} - \frac{6}{4n+3}=24\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4n-1)(4n+3)}$$ Now as $4n-1>n$ f0r $n>0$ and $4n+3>n$ so
$$\frac{1}{(4n-1)(4n+3)}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{n=0}^m(6/(4 n-1)-6/(4 n+3)) = -6/(4 m+3)-6$
where m is finite for the rearranging, but now we let it go $\to \infty$.
What happens?